# JPA: How to get the sum of a nested jsonb entity

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to return an object the sum of `points`, which is an integer, which belongs to an object, `foo` of type `jsonb`, which is being referenced by the main object `user`, however, the sum keeps ending up as a null value, even though I can see that is not the case when i just return everything from the table.

Here is what I have:

```
  @Query(
      nativeQuery = true,
      value =
          "SELECT u.user_id, "
              + "SUM(CAST(u.foo->>'points' AS INTEGER)) AS totalActivePoints "
              + "FROM banpoint.user u "
              + "WHERE u.user_id = :userId "
              + "AND (u.end_date IS NULL OR u.end_date > now()) "
              + "GROUP BY u.user_id "
  )
  Optional<Map<String, Object>> getPointSum(long userId);
```

My tables look like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo
(
    type                    TEXT            NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY,
    points                  INTEGER         NOT NULL,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user
(
    id                  BIGSERIAL       NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id             BIGINT          NOT NULL,
    start_date          TIMESTAMP       DEFAULT NULL,
    end_date            TIMESTAMP       DEFAULT NULL,

    foo                 JSONB           NOT NULL
);
```

Sample data from user table as json:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "userId" : 1234,
  "startDate" : 1656668960145,
  "endDate" : 1657273760146,
  "foo" : {
    "type" : "BOTS",
    "points" : 23
    }
  }
}

{
  "id" : 2,
  "userId" : 1234,
  "startDate" : 1656668960204,
  "endDate" : 1657878560146,
  "foo" : {
    "type" : "TRIGGERBOT",
    "points" : 14
    }
  }
}
```

How can I properly get the sum of this field properly, which belongs to the JSONB object?
Im using PSQL 14

EDIT:

also have tried it the following way, but the result is still null

```
  @Query(
      nativeQuery = true,
      value =
          "SELECT SUM(CAST(u.foo->'foo'->>'points' AS INTEGER)) AS totalActivePoints "
              + "FROM banpoint.user u "
              + "WHERE u.user_id = :userId "
              + "AND (u.end_date IS NULL OR u.end_date > now()) "
              + "GROUP BY u.user_id ")
  Integer getPointSum(long userId);
```

Additionally, returning a `List<Object>` instead of getting the sum ALSO returns a list with null  values in it as well...

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample JSON data. Your SQL query is also missing a `GROUP BY` clause. Btw: why does `user` have an `id` **and** a `user_id`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I can venture a guess that one is for internal use and the other is for external use, the external one being not sequential. Or IDs from different systems. There are so many options not relevant to this question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're right, forgot to update the post with the group by but now i have provided some same data when doing select * from user

Comment: [Works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6d78ffbd1e1c56eb78e0ef936421ae3b)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name okay that is very odd...then maybe its some spring/jpa crap that ruining the result. Changing the query to only return the sum and making the return type of the method as an Optional<Integer> doesnt seem to change anything though...

Comment: maybe because you have foo jsonb. but inside the jsonb you a 'foo' as key. [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=344213cb194c58917fba655fc8d44b66) @mrnoobynoob

Comment: @Mark damn I was hoping that would be it, but for some reason that still doesnt work for me. I should note (not that I think it should matter) that I cant cast the same exact way as you due to JPA complaining, but doing it via CAST(x as INTEGER) should be the same thing, in my mind. which also seems to work here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3e30e593ba9e8d1a507078d7393ae685 but not in my code

Comment: @mrnoobynoob can you try directly execute the query in psql. So that we can know it's java problem or sql query problem.

Comment: @Mark yes, I confirmed that my way works here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3e30e593ba9e8d1a507078d7393ae685

Comment: @mrnoobynoob now it's a java problem.  that part I am not  not fimilar. maybe should be `int getPointSum(long userId);`

Comment: @Mark ya must be a java problem now, and i originally tried that, but then since the query is returning null, in jpa, id get an error, so Integer should work for any case, but the result is still wrong.

Comment: @mrnoobynoob maybe you can replace `:userId` to `1234`  if still not working. Then it probably a java string format issue..

Comment: @Mark ya same output. gonna look into this more. thanks for your help though